# How can I read the STDOUT of a external Program in realtime?

Tags: perl, process, external, stdout

Let me elaborate.

Say I have perl program

(whch was shamelessly copied and edited from perl
http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-can-I-open-a-pipe-both-to-and-from-a-command%3f
)

```
 use IPC::Open3;

 use Symbol qw(gensym);   

 use IO::File;
 local *CATCHOUT = IO::File->new_tmpfile;
 local *CATCHERR = IO::File->new_tmpfile;

 my $pid = open3(gensym, ">&CATCHOUT", ">&CATCHERR", "ping -t localhost");

 #waitpid($pid, 0);   

seek $_, 0, 0 for \*CATCHOUT, \*CATCHERR;

 while( <CATCHOUT> ) {

print $_;
}
```

But the problem with the above program is it will to a sort of readtoEnd() of the STDOUT belonging to the program ping.exe in this case and allow it ti be read all at once.

But what I want to be able to do is to read the STDOUT as it is being written out to STDOUT.

if I remove waitforpid() then program exits immediately, so that doesn't help either.

Is that Possible ? If so, can you please point me in the right direction.

Update:
Drats!!!! I missed the | symbol... which is essential for piping the output out of ping and into the perl script!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the strengths (or weaknesses) of perl is that there is more than one way to do things.  This works:

```
perl -e 'open(F,"ping localhost|"); while(<F>) { s/ms/Milliseconds/; print $_; }'
```

Just put the s/ms/Milliseconds/ to show that the data is being read and changed
Not sure exactly what you have wrong with Open3

Answer (score 3):

```
use IPC::Open3 qw( open3 );

open(local *CHILD_STDIN, '<', '/dev/null') or die $!;

my $pid = open3(
   '<&CHILD_STDIN',
   my $child stdout,
   '>&STDERR',
   'ping', '-t', 'localhost',
);

while (<$child_stdout>) {
   chomp;
   print("Got: <<<$_>>>\n");
}

waitpid($pid, 0);
```

But that can be written as

```
open(my $ping_fh, '-|', 'ping', '-t', 'localhost') or die $!;

while (<$ping_fh>) {
   chomp;
   print("Got: <<<$_>>>\n");
}

close($ping_fh);
```

This just shows the proper usage. If these don't work, it's an unrelated problem: `ping` is buffering it's IO when not connected to a terminal. You can fool it using a pseudo-tty.